# Using PythonCall.jl to find type of Python object

Tags: julia

How do I use PythonCall.jl to detect the type of a returned python object that is a dict?

```
p = pydict(Dict("A"=>1))
typeof(p) == PyDict
false
```

Comment: The type `PyDict` is for going the opposite way: When you have a Python object and want to read it in Julia as an `AbstractDict`. The function `pydict` takes a Julia-side dictionary and converts it into a `Py`, an abstract Python object that supports `__getitem__`.

Comment: Say I have a dict object returned by python, a Py, how do I detect that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the type by calling `pytype` or checking the `__class__` property:

```
julia> pytype(p)
Python: <class 'dict'>

julia> p.__class__ 
Python: <class 'dict'>

julia> p.__class__ ==  @py dict
Python: True
```

or if you want a Julia object:

```
julia> Bool(p.__class__ ==  @py dict)
true
```